# Android get Sms Number From Title

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get numbers in sms inbox . I succeed it but i have another problem now.
Some companies send messages by using their name such as Ebay or Vodafone . When i try to get phone number , it only shows the name of company like this . I really need to get their number . Thanks for help guys :)

Adress : Vodafone

Person : null

Date : 1231321

Body : ....

```
  System.out.println("Mesaj Log Çıktıları");
            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",

                    "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    String threadid = c.getString(1);

                    String address = c.getString(2);
                    String person = c.getString(3);
                    String date = c.getString(4);
                    String body = c.getString(5);
                    System.out.println("******Mesaj "+id+"*******");
                    System.out.println("Thread id : "+threadid );
                    System.out.println("Gelen Adres : "+address);
                    System.out.println("Person : "+person);
                    System.out.println("Date : "+date);
                    System.out.println("Body : "+body);
                    if(address.equals("44434967")){
                        //a company phone number in inbox
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
```